# Distribution of the radius of a circle uniformly on a square

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

> Suppose U1, U2, . . . , V1, V2, . . . are independent Uniform(1, 1) random variables, so that (U1, V1), (U2, V2), . . . are independent points distributed uniformly over the square $[-1,1]^2$. Let Rn be the radius of the largest circle centred at the origin (0, 0) which contains none of the points (U1, V1), . . . , (Un,Vn). Find the density of the weak limit of $\sqrt{n}R_n$.

For this question I have looked at the hint and it gives me that
$$\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}R_n>r)=(1-(\pi r^{2})/(4n))$$

I am struggling to come to this conclusion the way I have thought about doing it after drawing a diagram was as follows :

$\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}R_n<r)=\mathbb{P}(R_n<r\sqrt{n})$ which I take is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(mindistance((U_1,V_1),(U_2,V_2),...) \geq r/\sqrt{n})$.

I then rewrote this as  $$[\mathbb{P}(distance(U_1,V_1) \geq r/\sqrt{n})]^{n}$$.

where I defined the distance between (0,0) and (U1,V1) as $\sqrt{U1^{2}+V1^{2}}$

I have tried following this through but never seem to get anywhere, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track. Now switch back to the complement, the probability for the distance to be less than $r\,/\sqrt n$. That's just the ratio between the area of the circle and the area of the square. That gives you the result provided in the hint (which is missing the exponent $n$), and then you can apply $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\mathrm e$.